# Is gcc's -Wsequence-point warning flag broken?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, sequence-points

I'm getting a warning for this line:

```
e = strtol(++s, (char **)&s, 10);
```

Moving the `++s` to a separate statement makes the warning go away, but as far as I can tell, this warning is completely incorrect. The *value* of `s` is only used once, in the computation of `++s`. The second use of `s` is only to take its address. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using gcc 4.4.3 or 4.4.5.  Post a full example.c that demonstrates it?

Comment: Ah, looks like it's the older 3.x gcc on that system.

Comment: By the way, post that as an answer and I'll accept it, since "current gcc does not generate this warning" is a good answer to my question about whether the warning was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of gcc (4.4.3 or 4.4.5) do not generate any warning for the line you posted.  The generation of the warning there appears to be a bug in older gcc versions.

Comment: See [GCC bug 18050](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18050)  - fixed in 4.4.0.